# Cargo version dependency picking algorithm?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is that the same

```
[dependencies]
for_each = "0.1"
```

as

```
[dependencies]
for_each = "0.1.2"
```

And

```
[dependencies]
for_each = "~0.1"
```

From description, it looks like the same, but from experimentation I am getting inconsistent results.

What is the subtle difference between those 3 variants of requiring dependencies?

---

It looks like ranges are:

```
0.1    :=  >=0.1.0, <0.2.0
0.1.2  :=  >=0.1.2, <0.2.0
~0.1   := >=0.1.0, <0.2.0
```

Right?

From these, it's clear that `0.1` and `~0.1` have the same range.
But I encountered a situation when `0.1` and `~0.1` give very different results.
Some subtle difference beyond ranges exists, and I don't understand what is that.

Comment: The first and the last one are the same – they translate to `>= 0.1.0, < 0.2.0`. The middle one translates to `>= 0.1.2, < 0.2.0`, though.

Comment: Note that dependency resolution can depend on your whole dependency graph. Cargo will try to minimise the number of versions of a single crate it picks, so it might choose a different version to satisfy a dependency somewhere else in the graph.

Answer (score 1):

```
0.1    :=  >=0.1.0, <0.2.0
0.1.2  :=  >=0.1.2, <0.2.0
~0.1   :=  >=0.1.0, <0.2.0
```

More details at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html.

---

Without the tilde, version compatibility is determined following the [SemVer](https://semver.org/) rules.
Cargo extended SemVer for `<1.0.0` versions:

> Cargo considers `0.x.y` to be compatible with `0.x.z`, where `y ≥ z` and `x > 0`.

On the other hand, **Tilde Requirements** seems to be something defined by Cargo:

> Tilde requirements specify a minimal version with some ability to update. If you specify a major, minor, and patch version or only a major and minor version, only patch-level changes are allowed. If you only specify a major version, then minor- and patch-level changes are allowed.